# Prolog: How to compose two "functions", to find the min of the squares of my list?

Tags: prolog, composition, function-composition

I'm learning prolog, and this is the question I have a bit of a problem with right now

> Write a Prolog function that takes two parameters: an input list, and
>   an output variable that is the smallest one among the squares of each
>   number in the input list

So far I've been able to make a squaring function

```
square([], []).  
square([First | Rest], [FirstSquared | SquareRest]) :-
    FirstSquared is First * First,
    square(Rest, SquareRest).
```

But I don't know how to call this new list as a parameter that would look something like this when pseudo-called in SWI-Prolog

```
min(square[result_List], Answer).
Answer = *minimum number of list of squares*
```

Or is there an easier way to implement this in Prolog? If you could please explain the logic behind why you do things a certain way in Prolog, that'd be great since I'm more used to coding in C++ and C#. Thanks!

Comment: in SWI, there is [min_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=min_list/2)/2

Comment: that's not what `least-squares` means. which is, to find the min of the sum of squares, among the possible variations.

Comment: Does the instructor/professor really call Prolog predicates *functions*? That's not a good sign.

Comment: @lurker do  you envision a call like `min_square(L,25)` here? an analogy with functions does have its place, IMO, were appropriate.

Comment: @WillNess even if a predicate is treated functionally, it's still not called a function in proper Prolog parlance. It infuses a functional mindset in the students, I think. But directly to your question, sure I would see `min_square(L, 25)` to be a reasonable query for such a predicate.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know least-squares meant that. But anyway yes the professor does call them functions. In this class we're sort of skimming over languages like Scheme, Prolog, Perl, etc. so we can become familiar with them...

Comment: @lurker Prolog can be used as a functional language too. (Some even claim it *should* be (ref: Huntbach "Agent-oriented programming: from Prolog to Guarded Definite Clauses") )

Comment: @WillNess yes of course it can. There are even predefined *predicates* that behave functionally. But they're called *predicates*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main paradigms when working in Prolog is state transformation. Your `square` (perhaps better named `squared`) predicate transforms a list into a list of squares; what's left is to find the minimum element in that list:

```
min_square(L, M):-
    squared(L, LS),
    min_list(LS, M).
```

Writing your own `min_list/2` should be straightforward. Just follow the same code skeleton that you used in the `squared/2` predicate.

After you've mastered that, the next step in your code development is to *fuse* the two processing stages into one, as @CapelliC proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785865/prolog-how-to-compose-two-functions-to-find-the-min-of-the-squares-of-my-lis/33786258#comment55339881_33786258), by adding one more argument to the `squared` relation, the *minimum-so-far*.

Comment: @CapelliC goes inside min_list, no? then the next step would be what you propose, the *fusion* of the two stages.